# EC2 Auto Scaling create-auto-scaling-group with two Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need to create auto-scaling-group with AWS CLI command. And that ASG needs to have two tags. I'm trying with:

```
aws autoscaling create-auto-scaling-group
--auto-scaling-group-name usr
--launch-configuration-name TEST
--min-size 0
--max-size 20
--vpc-zone-identifier subnet-xxxx
--tags ResourceId=usr,ResourceType=auto-scaling-group,Key=tag_1,Value=value_1,Key=Tag_2,Value=value_2,PropagateAtLaunch=true
```

After creating ASG have only last Tag `Tag_2` with value `value_2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define another tag after the first one by adding a <kbd>Space</kbd>:

```
aws autoscaling create-auto-scaling-group
--auto-scaling-group-name usr
--launch-configuration-name TEST
--min-size 0
--max-size 20
--vpc-zone-identifier subnet-xxxx
--tags ResourceId=usr,ResourceType=auto-scaling-group,Key=tag_1,Value=value_1,PropagateAtLaunch=true ResourceId=usr,ResourceType=auto-scaling-group,Key=tag_2,Value=value_2,PropagateAtLaunch=true
```